# What do you call a person without whom work does not get done?

Tags: synonyms

An **irreplaceable** person, in the context of getting work done.

Is there a word to describe such a person?

Comment: Please add an example sentence.

Comment: What's wrong with "irreplaceable"? Please explain in more detail what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I think the word you're looking for is:

- **linchpin**  ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/linchpin))

> the most important member of a group or part of a system, that holds together the other members or parts or makes it possible for them to operate as intended

You might also use :

- **key player** ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/key-player))

> an important person, company, etc. in a particular area of activity:

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

- **Indispensable** ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/indispensable))

> Something or someone that is indispensable is so good or important that you could not manage without it, him, or her:

> His long experience at the United Nations makes him indispensable to the talks.